# Spec file is being ignored in coverage

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have several spec files, but one of them is ignored when I generate the covarega

Checked the filename, imports

Comment: Did you check the codeCoverageExclude section in angular.json?

Comment: I dont have anything in this session

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.